# joomla module only working when logged in as a registered user

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.6

I am using a joomla sp accordian module for displaying a set of articles on a page. However, the accordian effect only shows up when I am logged in as a registered user. It does not show the accordian effect when I am logged out. I have set all of the access levels to public.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: We'll need to know what the module is or see the code to answer this question. I'd suspect something like: the module uses the user session to store something (which only exists if you're logged in).

Comment: It would also be helpful to know if you are on 1.5, 1.6, or 1.7 because it cannot be more than one of those. Quick and easy thing to look at is the source of the page when logged in and not logged in, you should see something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a punt on this being either:
a) some sort of cache issue (Joomla not browser)
b) a javascript error

For (a) turn off all caching - global config and system pluginand retest.

For (b) check mootools  is loading. Check the browser's error console for .js errors.
If the tabs module/plugin loads jquery check for noConflict mode - and also that only one instance of jQuery's .js file loads.